# Does the C# spec prohibit type inference based on default parameters?

Tags: c#, type-inference, specifications, default-parameters

In the following code I am trying to accomplish default type deduction in a factory pattern.  I would like to call the factory method with an arbitrary combination of arguments and have the generic type parameters inferred from the default parameters for the omitted arguments.  This attempt at that, however, results in error CS1750.  [CS1750 is mentioned in a handful of places in the roslyn repo](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/search?q=cs1750), but reviewing those didn't reveal much about the cause in this case.

The full text of the error is as follows:

> (parameter) S a = new S()
>
> A value of type 'S' cannot be used as a default parameter because there are no standard conversions to type 'S' [TypeInference]csharp(CS1750)

```
public class T {}
public class T0  : T {}
public class T1  : T {}
// T2{} .. T9{}
public class T10 : T {}
public struct S<T> {}
public class X {} // X is a complex object strongly-typed with T1..T10
public static class C {
    public static X Factory<A,B/*,C..J*/>(
        S<T0> s = new S<T0>(), // this is fine
        S<A>  a = new S<T0>(), // ERROR: no standard conversions to type...
        S<B>  b = new S<T0>()  // ...'S<A>' [TypeInference]csharp(CS1750)
        //S<C> c,
        //...
        //S<J> j
    )
    where A : T
    where B : T
    =>throw new System.NotImplementedException();

    static void usage1() {
        /* I'd like to be able to omit an arbitrary portion
           of the factory arguments and have type inference use
           the default values.*/
        Factory(b : new S<T1>());
    }

    // simplified example
    public static void Foo<A>(A a)    {}
    public static void Bar<A>(A a=42) {} // ERROR: CS1750

    static void usage2() {
        Foo(42); // this is fine
    }
}
```

I have been trying to understand why `CS1750` is raised.  According to [the 5th edition of the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf)

> 15.6.2 Method Parameters...
>
> The expression in a *default-argument* shall be one of the following:
> ...
>
> - an expression of the form new S() where S is a value type

`new S<T0>()` seem to meet this criterion.  Indeed, the parameter declaration `S<T0> s = new S<T0>()` doesn't seem to raise an error.

Reading (admittedly without completely absorbing) the spec's type inference section it wasn't obvious why default values wouldn't be considered during type inference.  The language in that section even seems to be careful to distinguish optional parameters with and without corresponding arguments.  For example, in this sentence a missing optional argument is excluded as cause for inference failure:

> 12.6.3 Type Inference...
>
> If ... there is a non-optional parameter with no corresponding argument, then inference immediately fails.

Rather than rule out default parameters, this seems more like a weak suggestion that type inference could be based on them.

1. Why is the compiler trying to convert `S<T0>` to `S<A>` instead of inferring `A` to be `T0`?
2. Does the spec prohibit type inference based on default parameters?

Comment: `where A : T` means A extends T.  `class T0 : T {}` means T0 extends T.  This means an instance of T0 isn't necessarily assignable to A: they share a base class, but they don't extend each other.  So an instance of S<T0> isn't assignable to S<A>, is it?  Am I missing something?

Comment: @RichN: I think you missed item #1 in the numbered list at the end of the question.

Comment: "there is a non-optional parameter with no corresponding argument" has nothing to do with type inference at all, it has to do with kicking that signature out of the set of candidate overloads

Comment: @RichN "So an instance of S<T0> isn't assignable to S<A>, is it?" I agree.  But A is a type parameter so why doesn't the compiler infer A to be T0 instead?

Comment: @alx9r That doesn't make any sense.  If you say, `public void Foo(string a = 42){}` do you expect `a` to just be inferred to be an `int` because an int can't be converted to a string?  No.  It tells you that it can't convert the default value to that parameter's type.  It's on you to either change the type of the parameter to match the default value, or change the default value to match the parameter's type.

Comment: @Servy: This question isn't discussing the case where the parameter has a fixed type.  The method is generic and the parameter in question is using a placeholder type.

Comment: @Servy I'm not sure how the example `public void Foo(string a = 42){}` applies.  `public void Foo<A>(A a = 42) {}` would be closer.  In the former `string` is not a type parameter whereas `A` is a type parameter in the latter.  I'm striving for type inference here, not conversion.  I have added a simplified example to the code sample above that produces the same error to hopefully make that clearer.

Comment: @BenVoigt But that doesn't *matter*.  You can't perform the conversion, regardless of whether it's a known type or a generic type.

Comment: @alx9r You say that you're not striving for a conversion, but an expression needs to be convertible to the type of the variable you want to put it in for the assignment to be valid.  So you *do* need the conversion to be valid, as the compiler is telling you, or it won't work.

Comment: @Servy: When the types match (as they would if inference were performed as OP wants) there would be no conversion.

Comment: @BenVoigt And when they don't you now have a violation of the static typing.  The whole point of static typing is to ensure that *that can't happen*.  It needs to be valid *every time*, not just sometimes.  Also, saying, "there is no conversion when the types match" doesn't make sense.  Anytime you assign something to a variable the expression needs to be convertible to that type.  The convertibility check of the assignment happens *at compile time*.  Whether the implementation of it is an identity conversion or a non-identity preserving one doesn't change that it exists.

Comment: @Servy: When they don't match, the prospective default argument has a violation of the static typing.  Which could be a compile error *at the call site* which is where the default argument expression has to be evaluated and passed.  The C# spec doesn't allow that deferral of the error, but it would be totally feasible, and the error would rarely occur in practice if it were deferred, because it would only happen if the argument were defaulted but the generic type parameters were specified explicitly to be incompatible.

Comment: @BenVoigt You're basically asking for templates not generics, which while they may appear similar on the face of things, are pretty radically different.  But regardless, this question is not a proposal for an entirely new language that functions entirely differently from C#, and if it is, that's very much not an appropriate question for SO for...a lot of reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question 1, I think, is 'the compiler doesn't work that way'.  The compiler expects, as I did in my comment, that the programmer provides a valid type for a default parameter based on the current type constraints.  The compiler won't infer a generic parameter for you based on the type of a default parameter.  Here the only constraints are that both A and T0 descend from T, so in general we can't expect `S<A> a = new S<T0>()` to work.  I'm pretty sure that's what the error means.

Your question 2 is really 'could it work that way?', I think.  I think it could theoretically, but there are some problems.  Consider what happens if, in your example, someone makes the call `C.Factory<T1, T1>()`, thus explicitly setting A to be of type T1 without providing any parameters.  Now we've got an error case when we try to assign `new S<T0>()` to our parameter a of type `S<A>` = `S<T1>`, since `S<T0>` is not assignable to `S<T1>`.  How should the compiler handle that?  Since A is only constrained to be a descendant of T, and Factory has an overload that takes no parameters, it looks like the call is valid.  So any exception is going to be confusing at best, and probably arguably wrong.  But we don't want to infer A to be T0 after the programmer has explicitly asked for a different type.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the reasoning in your second paragraph.  How is `C.Factory<T1,T1>()` more of a problem than `C.Factory<T1,T1>(s: new S<T0>(), a: new S<T0>()),b: new S<T0>())` with default parameters out of the picture?  It seems to me that in both cases there is a type mismatch between the type parameter and the corresponding type of the argument.  The only difference is that in the former the arguments are the defaults provided at the declaration, while in the latter the arguments are provided at the call site.

Comment: Yes, I suppose you're right: they are basically the same thing.  You're example is pretty obviously wrong just from the parameter types though.  We're passing an `S<T0>` instance to an `S<T1>` pointer.  It isn't immediately obvious with the defaults.

Comment: By the way, I expect you've realized this (and it wasn't the question), but you can do what you want with old-fashioned overloads.  In your simplified example just have methods `void Bar<A>(A a) {}` and `void Bar() { Bar(42); }`.

Comment: If I understand you correctly that would still mean something like n^2 overloads for n parameters to cover all combinations of omitted parameters.  Or did I misunderstand what you were driving at?

Comment: @RichN: The error isn't immediately obvious when defaults are used, but the compiler could still flag it at compile-time (at the call site using defaults and incompatible explicit generic type arguments).  No possibility of an unexpected exception.